# Scipy minimize(method=’SLSQP’) returns success even though constraints are not satisfied

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, minimize

I am trying to find a feasible point which satisfies a set of nonlinear constraints. I am using `scipy`'s Sequential Quadratic Programming (SQP) minimizer to do this. My simple example is

```
target = lambda x: 1
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: 1/2*np.sin(x[0])-0.48 + x[1]/150},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -np.sin(x[2])*-np.sin(x[1])-0.99})
bnds = ((0, 6), (0, 6), (0, 6))
res = minimize(target, (0, 0, 0), method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons, options={'disp':True, 'maxiter':10000})
```

However, the returned result is:

```
the value of g1: -0.48
the value of g2: -0.99
fun: 1.0
jac: array([0., 0., 0.])
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
nfev: 5
nit: 5
njev: 1
status: 0
success: True
x: array([0., 0., 0.])
```

It seems that even though the constraints are not satisfied at all (the values of `g1` and `g2` are all negative), the optimizer still thinks that it terminates successfully. I understand that by changing the initial point, for example, to (0, 0, 1), it will successfully find the correct feasible solution, but shouldn't SQP work for a not feasible initial point? If not, shouldn't `scipy` report failure (or bad initial point) instead of return a fake solution?